# Applying sklearn function to pandas dataframe gives ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y)

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

The following code gives an error message:

```
    >>> import pandas as pd
    >>> from sklearn import preprocessing, svm
    >>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [0,1,2], "b":[0,1,2], "c": [0,1,2]})
    >>> clf = svm.SVC()
    >>> df = df.apply(lambda x: preprocessing.scale(x))
    >>> clf.fit(df[["a", "b"]], df["c"])
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Alexander\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", lin
     151, in fit
        y = self._validate_targets(y)
      File "C:\Users\Alexander\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", lin
     515, in _validate_targets
        check_classification_targets(y)
      File "C:\Users\Alexander\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.
    y", line 173, in check_classification_targets
        raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y)
    ValueError: Unknown label type: 0   -1.224745
    1    0.000000
    2    1.224745
    Name: c, dtype: float64
```

The dtype of the pandas DataFrame is not an object, so applying the sklearn svm function should be fine, but for some reason it does not recognize the classification labels. What is causing this issue?

Comment: Try `df[["a", "b"]].values` and `df["c"].values` SKLearn usually expects arrays, not dataframes.

Comment: Same problem, the error message is:

Comment: raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y)
ValueError: Unknown label type: array([-1.22474487,  0.        ,  1.22474487])

Comment: When I try to run `df = df.apply(lambda x: preprocessing.scale(x))` I get an error. `TypeError: ("Cannot cast ufunc subtract output from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') ...`

Comment: That's weird - I get some warnings, which I omitted, but no error messages.. what version of python are you using? I am using Python 2.7.11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that after your scaling step, the labels are float-valued, which is not a valid label-type; if you convert to `int` or `str` it should work:

```
In [32]: clf.fit(df[["a", "b"]], df["c"].astype(int))
Out[32]: 
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape=None, degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='rbf',
  max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
  tol=0.001, verbose=False)
```